# Menu items' links are not working properly and added images

Tags: plugins, menus

I did a wordpress project localhost using MAMP in Mac os,when I'm import the data to window 7.
I have 6 Menu items

[image]

there are some images and they are not displaying(I'm using revolutio slider) 
Menu items are also not working properly when i click menu i got this error

for about me
[image]

when click weekly-seller-reports
[image]

and other problem is I duplicate same project and database in MAC OS wordpress_test1(original one) and other is wordpress_test2.But in wordpress_test2 project when I click menu items it will redirect to wordpress_test1 project page

how can i fix this error?,plz need quick help... thanx

Answer (score 0):

Does it work in your mamp environment ?

If it works then the problem could be that the files are not moved properly from the uploads directory or the database is not imported properly.

Please try once again.

Comment: yes it is working properly in MAMP environment but i try about 3 times same result...

Comment: try changing the .htaccess file.

Comment: can u explain more..

Comment: share the htaccess code and localhost url that how u are accessing the local website

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_test1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_test1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: in windows :-http://localhost/wordpress_test1/ ,in MAC :-http://localhost:8888/wordpress_test1/

Comment: rest of the pages are working ? if not check wether mod rewrite is enabled or not. Admin accessible ?

Comment: pages can be manual access but using main menu i can't go to pages

Comment: Then try to regenerate the menus

Answer (score 0):

1. Settings > Permalink,  Flush your permalink by pressing save.
2. Import all you media directory to your new setup.
   Thats all!